# Angular 4 - ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error as I'm trying to get a median of an array.

moniesService.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReferenceCompany } from '../../shared';



@Injectable()
export class ReferenceCompanyService {
basisPoint: number;
medianRate: number;
highMiddle: number;
lowMiddle: number;
rateList: Array<number> = [];
refCompanies: ReferenceCompany[];
index: number;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

// my HTTP calls which I erased them.

// Median Rate
addRateToArray() {
    this.index = 0;
    for (const i of this.refCompanies) {
        this.rateList.push(this.refCompanies[this.index].fx_rate);
        this.index++;
    }
    for (let j = 0; j <= this.rateList.length; j++) {
        console.log(this.rateList[j]);
    }
}

// Calculate the Median and Basis point
median() {
    this.addRateToArray();
    this.rateList.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    this.lowMiddle = Math.floor((this.rateList.length - 1) / 2);
    this.highMiddle = Math.ceil((this.rateList.length - 1) / 2);
    this.medianRate = (this.rateList[this.lowMiddle] + this.rateList[this.highMiddle]) / 2;
    this.basisPoint = this.medianRate / 10000;
}

}
```

referenceCompany.ts interface

```
export class ReferenceCompany {
_id: string;
name: string;
fx_rate: number;
}
```

So the logic is, I have reference companies in my database which each company has an id, name and fx_rate.

So what I'm doing is i'm pushing each fx_rate from each company to temp array and from there I'm calculating the median.

I am able to get the median rate,  but the thing is when I click first on the button to get the median rate it gives me this error.

```
`ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
```

for

```
`addRateToArray()`
```

and on the second click, I'm able to get the median rate with no error.

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how is `refCompanies` populated

Comment: @Ric with service :
   // [GET]
        getRefCompanies(): Observable<ReferenceCompany[]> {
           return this.http.get<ReferenceCompany[]>
        ('http://localhost:3000/api/referenceCompanies')
            .do((res => console.log(res)));
       }

and I'm calling it with function:
getRefCompanies() {
    this._referenceService.getRefCompanies()
      .subscribe(refCompanies =>
        this.refCompanies = refCompanies
      );
  }


ngOnInit() {
    this.getCompanies();
    this.getRefCompanies();
}

Comment: what is the `console.log` for in the service? a mistake? you should do the subscribe within the `ngOnInit` the problem is the async nature of it, `ngOnInit` completes before your `getRefCompanies` does/

Comment: I subscribed it within `ngOnInit` but it only populates refCompanies with one entry. [Angular Tutorial with Async and Await](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20170127-Angular2TutorialWithAsyncAndAwait.html) I'm reading this maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with asynchronous data, you probably need to instantiate a new instance. Have you tried instantiating a new reference of 'ReferenceCompany'?

```
refCompanies: ReferenceCompany[] = new ReferenceCompany();
```

Comment: Thank I could get rid of the error by adding  refCompanies: ReferenceCompany[] = new Array<ReferenceCompany>();

Comment: but now instead off an error I get "Nan" not a number error, on the first click and get a correct value on the second click.

Comment: Probably related to the issue I mentioned in the comment.

Comment: You can initialize some dummy values for the model, if that's the problem.

Comment: I'm just using button for testing purpose, but my main concern is to get the median onload. by initializing the `rateList[]` I'm getting a median for dummy  numbers. So some how I have to populate `rateList[]` with `fx_rate` from `refCompanies` before calculating the median. I feel like i'm doing it but of course i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Just set the getRefCompanies function as a promise. When the data is loaded, populate rateList.